Import multiple rows into a temp table in one round trip via SqlDataRecord
This problem is just starting to show up into the profiler. We have something that looks like this:
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) 
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #Ids VALUES (@0);";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter() { ParameterName = "@0", DbType = GetDbType() });

    cmd.Prepare();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        ((IDbDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[0]).Value = value;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

We're looking at the possibility of speeding this up by decreasing the number of round trips. Using DataTable here would be a monstrosity but there's this type SqlDataRecord that seems to fit, so we should be able to do something like this:
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) 
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #Ids SELECT * FROM @0;";

    var param  = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@0";
    // FIXME more properties
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    param.Value = values.Cast<T>().Select((x) => {
                             // FIXME Create new SqlDataRecord
                         }.ToList();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

The main difficulty here that makes this different from the other samples is the T; this code is dynamic and receives a huge number of possible types; thus CREATE TYPE won't work. There's no way creating a type for every possible VARCHAR length is happening.
How do I fill in the FIXME comments above?
Related question, no good answers: How would I create a temp table in SQL Server when I have a big list of ID's
In comments there's an ask for the bigger picture. There really isn't a very good way to get more information by zooming out here. There's exactly one copy of the routine that sets arguments to all SQL calls (read: stored procedures) in the codebase, and this is it.
The scale factor for number of rows is fat tailed; the average number of rows is less than 10 but the maximum size is very large and calls with over a thousand happen regularly. Thus we load a temp table; and on conversion to do something other than a foreach loop we still load a temp table.

You can create multiple rows with just one INSERT INTO command - see this question

Why don't you use SqlBulkCopy? Also assuming you are just using this temp table for joins, why not use a Table Valued Parameter?

@stuartd: Well if you want to do all the string escaping yourself ... (number of rows is not fixed).

I'm confused: you can use SqlBulkCopy with a #temp table, and you can give it an existing open connection. What exactly are you saying?

I don't know what you are talking about, what doesn't work exactly? I have code that does exactly this and works fine. You just need to keep the connection open and hand it to SqlBulkCopy otherwise the temp table gets dropped.

Your options are; 1) include multiple statements in a single .CommandText. 2) pass an array as a json string. 3) SqlBulkCopy. 4) Table Value Parameter (TVP).

This might be a little voodo, but string_split could help if your db supports it. but I also would recommend just straightforwardly write multiple insert in one single command.
However, a query with thousands of ids might indicate there's something very wrong.

Doesn't the very own documentation of SqlDataRecord class (especially the Examples) answer your question (on how to fill in the FIXME comment)?

Just use a csv string and split it or a json if you have complex data. If you really like complication, make two cases for <5 rows and rest

"There's exactly one copy of the routine that sets arguments to all SQL calls (read: stored procedures) in the codebase, and this is it." sounds like a really bad idea. You should use some kind of mapper or code generation to generate the correct code for each procedure.

@Charlieface: Would you really rather see this question wrapped up in a code generator?

It sounds like a TVP might not be the right fit for you.
But you can use a temp table with SqlBulkCopy, which will be much much faster than individual inserts.
You can pass SqlBulkCopy either a DataTable or a DbDataReader. The former is simple to create, but can be memory-heavy. You can create a reader simply using the free FastMember library.
using var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringFromSomewhere());
await conn.OpenAsync();
var createTable = $"CREATE TABLE #ids (Id {columnTypeHere} PRIMARY KEY);";
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(createTable, conn)) 
{
    // do NOT pass any parameters for this command, otherwise it gets wrapped as sp_executesql and the table will be dropped immediately
    // cmd.Prepare() is unnecessary and counter-productive

    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}

using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data)) 
{
    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "#ids";
    await bulk.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
}

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("someStoredProcedure", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(  // etc
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}


So, I don't know why the previous programmer could not get SqlBulkCopy working; but I managed it. new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock) -> booom; but new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null) -> works.

What error did you get?

Invalid object name.

Weird, I can't imagine why that would make a difference, as long as you aren't passing any parameters for the first command, and you aren't closing/disposing the connection.

A fully working example.
using var connection = new SqlConnection(@"...");
connection.Open();
int[] values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TYPE dbo.Ids AS TABLE (Id INT );";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}

using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #Ids (Id INT);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}

using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #Ids SELECT * FROM @0;";

    var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@0";
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    param.TypeName = "dbo.Ids";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    var record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int));

    param.Value = values.Cast<int>()
        .Select(x =>
        {
            //var record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int));
            record.SetInt32(0, x);
            return record;
        })
        //.ToList()
        ;

    var affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine($"Rows inserted: {affectedRows}");
}

using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Ids;";
    var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine($"Count: {count}");
}


You need to check for 0 count in values in which case you pass null not the IEnumerable. And you are missing the TypeName to specify the table type. Also you can shorten this a bit cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@0", SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "dbo.SomeTableType", Value = ienumerableOrNullHere });

Apologies; I oversimplified the question and there was something critical omitted that I couldn't tell was missing until reading your answer.
